# python print function fails when the script uses a lot of memory

Tags: python, printing

I've been working with python for a while and I frequently encounter the following problem.

I write a multi-stepped program and insert print statement at the beginning and the end of each step to monitor the execution of the program and print out current state. 
However, when the program occupies large quantity of ressource (CPU/RAM), the print function fails to show messages one by one as the process executes and shows them all together at once at the end of the whole program. 
Does anyone know the reason? 
thx

Comment: You might be better using actual logging, rather than relying on the interpreter to print out the messages, particularly if your program is using a lot of CPU/RAM - why waste those resources on `print`?

Comment: you're right. But for simple dev (not production), print should be suffice instead of logging.

Comment: Well evidently not, in this case, as you're having problems with too much printing! Have you considered e.g. cutting down the number of prints (every 10th, 100th, 1000th iteration)?

Answer (score 0):

This could be the issue with command line allotted buffer as well. You could try execute the script with unbuffered option as below:

```
python -u <script to be executed> <command line args>
```